# Azure Application Insights shows the same event at identical timestamps multiple times

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am tracking custom events in Application Insights. In this problematic case I issue one call to "trackEvent" in my browser-front-end when the user loads a component (I am developing an Angular application).

In my Application Insights I run a query to list my custom events. Now in the results-list I have the same events with all fields identical (even the timestamp with miliseconds). Only the itemId is different.

Where could those multiple events of just one call to trackEvent have originated?

I do not have any relevant source code to offer, since I am only using this one call of **trackEvent** in the library **applicationinsights-js** (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS)

Well here it goes:

```
AppInsights.trackEvent(myName, myProperties, myMeasurements);
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220961/application-insights-reporting-duplicate-events-for-each-server-request

Comment: Thanks! In my case the tracking-data is sent directly to a microsoft-server (services.visualstudio.com/v2/track, I can see the request in the browser-console, so there is nothing happing on the side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I could solve the problem by setting

```
config.isStorageUseDisabled = true;
```

in the configuration-object that is passed to the downloadAndSetup-Method of Application-Insights-JS. I also set the maxBatchInterval to 0, so that I would not lose any Tracking-Events. I am not sure about that though.