# Azure Application Insights showing duplicate entries

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We are using Azure Function App, Azure SQL server and API management a very simply solution and we are reporting all our telemetry back to Application Insights.
Right now we are trying to review some performance issue and what we are observing is that Application Insights is showing duplicate records (screenshot below). Anyone know how we can avoid this duplicate entries and have a clean hierarchical flow of telemetry data?

[image]

Update 01/04/2022: Following is the list of Dlls from the Function App and I am not sure if this is the one causing duplication

[image]

UPDATE: 01/05/2022:  We created a new Application Insights Instance and just created out of the box Function App From Azure portal and attached this instance of App Insights (no custom code nothing just sample code) and still we see DUPLICATE telemetry for that new function App as shown below from the App Insights logs:

[image]

Comment: Could you please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220961/application-insights-reporting-duplicate-events-for-each-server-request , may it helps..

Comment: Thank you @AjayKumarGhose-MT , I will check this out and confirm if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Hello @user42012 , Any update on this..!?

Comment: hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT I am still trying to work with my Dev team on this, as we are using Function Apps and trying to locate where we have 2 AI dlls as we getting every entry duplicate. I will repost once we are able to find out the root cause.

Comment: hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT I tried to search in the FunctionApp and I have attached the screenshot of the dlls in the function app (Application Insights dll) not sure if that is causing the duplication (Check the screenshot of dlls in original post, I have updated it today 01/04/2022)

Comment: hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT deleting the dlls also didnt help and we still are seeing duplicate App Insights logs, we created altogether a new function App and new Application Insights instance as well and still the same issue (duplicate Telemetry).

Comment: hi, anyone able to resolve this case?

Comment: @msk in my case it was Microsoft code issue and they had acknowledged it. Not sure if it was fixed or not as I had to move on to a different project post it.

Comment: @msk I also tried to follow it up on Github in case if you want to reopen this case :  https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2509

Comment: Thanks @user42012 ,  I will follow it up!

Answer (score 3):

If your application insights is workspace-based, the app logs are stored in the workspace, AI SDK will collect them once, and diagnostics setting will collect them again, so there is duplicate logs in the workspace. Here, you can delete the diagnostic setting, or remove the destination of the workspace which is part of diagnostic setting.

Kindly check if this is the case for you.

> Referenced from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/883344/application-insights-duplicate-telemetry

If you're using terraform and have diagnostics setting resource, removing `log_analytics_workspace_id = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.id` might also help.